# Position an object with findPos quirksmode

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to position a `div` with the written method `findPos()` but I don't know how to start out. Google did not help me so much.

**findPos**:

```
function findPos(obj) {
    var curleft = curtop = 0;

    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);

        return [curleft, curtop];
    }
}
```

**My code**:

```
fname.onfocus = function() {

    tooltip("Insert name", fname);
}

function tooltip(text, form) {

    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = "tool";
    var info = document.createTextNode(text);
    div.appendChild(info);
    form.parentNode.insertBefore(div, form.nextSibling);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand what are you trying to achieve, but I will try.

`findPos()` is a function that takes an element inserted in the DOM and returns its left and top position. The element *has to be inserted* in the DOM and you cannot use this function to set position of a created element.

To set a position use for example:

```
// you can use CSS for this instead of JS
div.style.position = "absolute";
div.style.top  = "300px";
div.style.left = "200px";
```

For more information have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position